# Is a ruby's Timestamp class equivalent to PostgreSQL's timestamp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

If I make a model and create a field like "name" along with a `Timestamp`, will it be equivalent to a timestamp created manually through a query like:

```
CREATE TABLE whatever (
name varchar(25)
created timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

In other words, if I'm dealing with a database that has the timestamp pre-created by hand, how do I create a model to match pre-existing records?

I imagine it's important so that I'm able to ActiveRecord queries without anything breaking on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord will understand the `timestamp` part of the schema so you should get an `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` out of the database just like you'd get with any other `timestamp` column. However, AR won't understand `default current_timestamp` so it will set your `created` column to `NULL` (or `nil` in Ruby land) and the `default current_timestamp` will never be triggered; I usually get around that with an [`after_initialize`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find) hook:

```
after_initialize :set_defaults, :if => :new_record?
#...
def set_defaults
    self.created = Time.now
end
```